# Redirecting to a specific page based on the incoming push notification message in ionic 5 -FCM

Tags: ionic-framework, redirect, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, ionic5

I am sending a notification to the phone with FCM. According to a code in this notification, I want to redirect to that page when opening the application. How can I do it? The code below opens the home page of the application directly.

in app.components.ts:

```
    this.fcm.onNotification().subscribe(data => {
      var noti_data = data['body'].split(" ");
      var noti_type = noti_data[noti_data.length-1];

        if (data.wasTapped) {
          if(noti_type == "XX001")
          {
            alert("111");
            this.route.navigate(['/address']);
          }
          else if (noti_type == 'XX002')
          {
            alert("222");
            this.route.navigate(['/home/address2']);
          }
          else if (noti_type == 'XX003')
          {
            alert("333");
            this.route.navigate(['/home/address3']);
          }
          console.log('Received in background');
        } else {
          console.log('Received in foreground');
        }
    });
```

It works when I put the same code block in foreground.

Comment: are you getting any alert in background when you tap on notifications?

Comment: No. Loader is running and home page opens. @NajamUsSaqib

Comment: Try to console.log `noti_data` inside `data.wasTapped` and see whats inside it. is it even getting conosle.log.

Comment: Data comes in when the application is open on the screen. But the alert in onNotification() doesn't work when it is closed. @NajamUsSaqib

Comment: Connect your device and send notification and console.log your data. when you tap on notification then open your console and see what data is in console. My question is data.wasTapped even working?

Comment: It always seems false. What does it do and where can I open it? @NajamUsSaqib

Comment: are you using cordova or capacitor?

Comment: It's cordova. @NajamUsSaqib